# Is there a way to programmatically extract the feed of a podcast from the iTunes page?

Tags: screen-scraping, itunes, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the latest podcasts from itunes store with link by RSS, JSON or something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816881/get-the-latest-podcasts-from-itunes-store-with-link-by-rss-json-or-something)

From an iTunes page, like http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-week-in-tech-mp3-edition/id73329404, is there a way to extract the corresponding feed address? In this case it would be http://leoville.tv/podcasts/twit.xml.

I know that if you open on iTunes you can extract it manually, but I want to do it programmatically. There's a link to the website of the podcast, but it may not be accurate. In this case it points to a web site with 20 podcasts on it.

Comment: A month later, but I just addressed this question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816881/get-the-latest-podcasts-from-itunes-store-with-link-by-rss-json-or-something/2887010#2887010). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this same problem recently and decided to write a php script to solve my woes. to anyone looking to extract a podcast feed from iTunes, i created a script that you can either input the iTunes Store URL or search with keywords straight on the iTunes store:

http://itunes.so-nik.com

for the source visit: http://snipplr.com/view/52465/

Comment: this php script seem to be broken, if yo copy paste it, it won't work

Comment: @Gino - just try http://xtunes-podcatcher.com/tools - this seems to work.